# Using Java to access a third party DLL

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface, jna

I am trying to write a Java program for scientific research equipment that uses National Instruments drivers (DLL) that are written in C.  I know nothing about these DLLs at the moment.  I can contact NI through my client to get details if required.

My C/C++ skills are ancient so would prefer avoiding anything that requires writing C/C++ code.

Looking for advice that includes pointing me to tutorials.  My Java skills are excellent and current it is just my C/C++ that is like a decade old.

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686504/is-there-a-ikvm-for-java-can-i-run-net-assemblies-on-a-jvm

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: immibis - how about - How to access a third party library without writing a C/C++ wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option in your case would likely be [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna).

Here is a simple [Hello World example](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md) to show you what is involved in mapping the C library's `printf` function:

```
package com.sun.jna.examples;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;

/** Simple example of JNA interface mapping and usage. */
public class HelloWorld {

    // This is the simplest way of mapping, which supports extensive
    // customization and mapping of Java to native types.

    public interface CLibrary extends Library {
        CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary)
            Native.loadLibrary((Platform.isWindows() ? "msvcrt" : "c"),
                               CLibrary.class);

        void printf(String format, Object... args);
    }

    // And this is how you use it
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CLibrary.INSTANCE.printf("Hello, World\n");
        for (int i=0;i < args.length;i++) {
            CLibrary.INSTANCE.printf("Argument %d: %s\n", i, args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

JNA's [JavaDoc](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.1.0/) and [github project](https://github.com/twall/jna) include examples and tutorials for a wide range of use cases.